# Create a grouped barplot with percentages and respective value labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Following is the dataframe for which I want to create a grouped barplot

```
df <- structure(list(Race = c("Caucasian/White", "African American", "Asian", "Other"), 'Hospital 1' = c(374, 820, 31, 108), 'Hospital 2' = c(291, 311, 5, 15), 'Hospital 3' = c(330, 206, 6, 5), 'Hospital 4' = c(950, 341, 6, 13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

To be precise, I want to group each Hospital according to 'Race'. Each hospital bars should be represented as percentages with their corresponding value labels.

Not a programmer basically, but trying to learn.

Comment: You may find this site useful: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(contains("Hospital"), names_to = "hospital", values_to = "count") %>% 
  group_by(hospital) %>% 
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = hospital, y = percent, fill = Race) +
  geom_col(position = "stack")
```

Comment: Thank you @Will Oldham for the efforts. But, what you suggested is a stacked plot. I am looking forward to a plot like https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvDmV.png

Comment: Then change the position argument in `geom_col()` to "dodge".